# Comparing two ArrayLists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two arrayList of the same Type and I want to compare the two based on a particular attribute in the ValueList.
ValueList

```
ValueList A contains
1,10,5,
2,20,3
3,40,5,
4,60,8

ValueList B contains
2,20,3
3,40,5
```

I want to compare both the list based on line_num and create another arraylist Result and if the line_num is present in ValueList A but not in ValueList B, then the value field in the Result  has to have a -1. Result should be like;

```
Result
10,-1
20,3
40,5,
60,-1
```

I am not able to write the 'Not Found' Condition. Could someone please help me?

My code

```
List<Result> result= new ArrayList<Result>();
for(ValueList data1: valueListA) {
    for (ValueList data2: valueListB) {
        Result inter = new Result();
        if(data1.getLine_num==data2.getLine_num) {
            inter.setKey(data1.getKey());
            inter.setValue(data1.getValue());
            result.add(inter);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated Code which works:

```
public static  List<Result> result;= new ArrayList<Result>();
    ....

  int i1 = 0,int i2 = 0;
  Result inter = new Result();
  while (i1 < valueListA.size() && i2 < valueListB.size()) {
  ValueList data1 = valueListA.get(i1);
  ValueList data2 = valueListB.get(i2);
  if (data1.getLine_num == data2.getLine_num) {
  // Add the result.      
  result= new ArrayList<Result>();

  inter.setValue(data1.getValue());
  inter.setKey(data1-getKey())
  result.add(inter);
  i1++;
  i2++;
 } else if (data1.getLine_num < data2.getLine_num) {
 result= new ArrayList<Result>();
  // Add -1 because the data was not in valueListB.
   inter.setValue(data1.getValue());
  inter.setKey(-1);
  result.add(inter);
  i1++;
  } else {
   i2++;
 }
```

}

Comment: Why not simply use `List#contains`? Override `ValueList#hashCode` and `ValueList#equals`.

Comment: what if a row contained in B but not A? are you going to simply ignore that? what if you have 2 items in A that have same line_num while there is only 1 item in B with such line_num? What if there are 2 matching items in B for an item in A?

Comment: @AdrianShum: if a row is in B and not in A, it is ignored.The line_num is unique and there wil be no duplicates

Comment: I think you should remove that updated code since it could be confusing for those who will read your question in the future and wonder if it's the solution of not (it isn't the working one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an algorithm point of view:

Add a boolean variable `found` that equals to `false` before the start of the inner loop. Then when you found one, you set it to `true`.

After the loop, you test the variable `found` and if it's false, you add -1.

```
List<Result> result= new ArrayList<Result>();
for(ValueList data1: valueListA){
    boolean found = false;
    for (ValueList data2: valueListB){
        Result inter= new Result();
        if(data1.getLine_num==data2.getLine_num){
           inter.setKey(data1.getKey());
           inter.setValue(data1.getValue());
           result.add(inter);
           found = true;
           break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
       result.add(...)
    }
}
```

However, Java allows better solutions, see the other answers for that.

But, if the lists are sorted like in your example, you have better algorithms. You can use a single while loop and 2 indexes (one per list). The complexity will drop from O(N*M) to O(N+M).

```
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
while (i1 < valueListA.size() && i2 < valueListB.size()) {
   ValueList data1 = valueListA[i1];
   ValueList data2 = valueListB[i2];
   if (data1.getLine_num == data2.getLine_num) {
      // Add the result.
      i1++;
      i2++;
   } else if (data1.getLine_num < data2.getLine_num) {
      // Add -1 because the data was not in valueListB.
      i1++;
   } else {
      i2++;
   }      
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do the way you had suggested(the second way) but the problem is, when the second object is added, it rewrites the 1st object and both first and second object are the same. So at the end, if I am supposed to get 5 objects in the result, all the 5 objects will be the same and will be the last object

Comment: @user2236033 I need to see the code, can you post it somewhere? Are you doing "new Result()" each time?

Comment: @user2236033 move `Result inter = new Result();` to where you add.

Comment: like this?       if (data1.getLine_num == data2.getLine_num) { // Add the result. Result inter = new Result(); inter.setValue(data1.getValue()); inter.setKey(data1-getKey()) result.add(inter);

Comment: @user2236033 yes and also where you insert -1. Otherwise you will keep modifying the same result object. That's why you have 5 identical objects.

Answer (score 1):

If `ValueList` `line_num` is `String` then compare like this:

```
if(data1.getLine_num.equals(data2.getLine_num))
```

---

Otherwise, implement `equals()` method in `ValueList` class and compare like:

```
if (data1.equals(data2)) 

public class ValueList {
    ....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (!(o instanceof ValueList)) 
             return false;

         ValueList other= (ValueList)o;

         if (this.line_num != other.line_num)
            return false;

         ....
         return true;
    }
```

Comment: ValueList; line_num is int

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method equals in ValueList:

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         if (obj == null)
            return false;
         if (obj == this)
            return true;
         if (!(obj instanceof ValueList))
            return false;

         ValueList other= (ValueList) obj;

         return other.getLineNum() == this.getLineNum();
    }
```

Then:

```
List<Result> result= new ArrayList<Result>();
for(ValueList data1: valueListA) {
    Result inter= new Result();
    if (valueListB.contains(data1)) {
         inter.setKey(data1.getKey());
    } else {
         inter.setKey("-1" /* or -1 */);
    }
    inter.setValue(data1.getValue());
    result.add(inter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I asked in the comment, what if a row contained in B but not A? are you going to simply ignore that? what if you have 2 items in A that have same line_num while there is only 1 item in B with such line_num? What if there are 2 matching items in B for an item in A?

You have to be clear on what you are trying to do.

From your code, it seems that whenever there is a matching "line_num" in list B, you will insert the "key+value" as a result in the result list.

if so, making use of a Set which contains all the line numbers in bList is easiest and most reasonable.

```
Set<Integer> bLineNums =new HashSet<Integer>();
for (ValueList v : bList) {
  bLineNums.add(v.getLineNum());
}
```

after you have the set, everything is easy, in psuedo code, it looks like this:

```
for (ValueList a : aList) {
  if (bLineNums.contains(a.getLineNum)) {
    result.add(new Result(a.getKey(), a.getValue()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ValueList` data should probably define its `equals()` method properly, by comparing `getKey()` values. Then you can use

```
List<Result> result= new ArrayList<Result>();
for (ValueList data1: valueListA){
    Result inter = new Result();
    inter.setKey(data1.getKey());
    if (valueListB.contains(data1)) {
        inter.setValue(data1.getValue());
    } else {
        inter.setValue(-1);
    }
    result.add(inter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the first value in List 1  the each and every values, if a value is not matching then have a condition to check is the list.hasNext() then you can handle the not found condition making sure that the we have checked all the values in the list.